# .NET - How to find the highest common base class from a Collection of Objects

Tags: .net, class, inheritance

I have an application which uses several levels of class inheritance. I wanted to know that if  I had a collection of objects which derive from Base Class e.g. simply

```
IEnumerable<BaseClass>
```

How can I find the highest common Type which all objects in the collection derive from, if other than BaseClass?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Type baseType = null;

foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    if (baseType == null)
        baseType = obj.GetType();
    else
    {
        Type currentType = obj.GetType();

        while (!baseType.IsAssignableFrom(currentType))
            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    }
}
```

This code will work only for actual inheritance hierarchy, not for interface hierarchies.